# How to avoid `circular dependencies` when loading pdfAnnotate in svelte?

Tags: javascript, pdf, svelte, circular-dependency, pdf-annotations

I would like to use [pdfAnnotate](https://github.com/highkite/pdfAnnotate) in svelte, but when I start the app, `npm run dev` complains about `Circular dependencies`. I did not find any example, how to fix this error. Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong, or point me to a solution?

To reproduce my problem:

```
  # 1. install svelte-pdf
  npx degit sveltejs/template my-svelte-project
  npm install
  npm install svelte-pdf
  cp ../../example.pdf public/
  # now add to src/App.svelte see below [1]
  npm run dev
  # now the webpage <host>:5000 works fine and shows the pdf

  # 2. install pdfAnnotate 
  npm install annotpdf
  # now add it to src/App.svelte, too, see below [2].
  npm run dev
  # says "Ciruclar dependencies" and the page <host>:5000 is blank.
```

where I added in step [1] to `src/App.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import PdfViewer from 'svelte-pdf';
</script>
<main>
  <PdfViewer url='./example.pdf' />
</main>
```

and in step [2] to `src/App.svelte`:

```
<script>
  import AnnotationFactory from 'annotpdf';
</script>
```

(I added the lines inside the existing `script` and `main` elements,
I did not use multiple such elements.)

The full error message is:

```
(!) Circular dependencies
node_modules/annotpdf/lib/object-util.js -> node_modules/annotpdf/lib/array-util.js -> node_modules/annotpdf/lib/object-util.js
node_modules/annotpdf/lib/object-util.js -> node_modules/annotpdf/lib/array-util.js -> /home/lst/tmp/pdf/pdfjs-svelte-app/node_modules/annotpdf/lib/object-util.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/annotpdf/lib/object-util.js
```

Comment: It said in clear text that `annotpdf/lib/object-util.js` and `annotpdf/lib/array-util.js` circularly depends on one another. Not your fault. The lib did it. Not sure how to fix though. Is it a warning or an error? If warning just ignore.

Comment: Thanks hackape! Your comments helped me to debug the issue further: as you suspected, the circular dependencies are not the culprit, but a harmless warning. If you add your comment as answer, I will accept it and open a new question about the real troublemaker...

Comment: No problem. I don't feel it worth posting as an answer so I'll pass. If you like you can answer your own question, that actually makes more sense since you have more info than I do.